# How to get a specific data from the <SCRIPT> tag in HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, testcomplete

I'm using TestComplete test automation tool with Javascript language for test scripts creation.

I need to get a specific data from HTML page source.

Here's what I see using Ctrl-U:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<SCRIPT>
~some script~;
</SCRIPT>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
~a few lines  with tags~
  <STYLE>
  …
  ...
  </STYLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY style="display:none">
  <SCRIPT>
  cWebBase="~someValue~";
  cWebImgs="~someValue~";
  cWebStyle="~someValue~";
  cUID="someUserID";   // the value between quotation marks is my target
  ...=true;
  window.name="~someName~";
  ...=window;
  iUserRefresh=0;
  cEnv="~some value~";
  </SCRIPT>
...
```

I'm familiar with Xpath, HTML and Javascript basics but can't figure out what's the fastest and easiest way here.
I'd appreciate any help/guidance here, thanks.

Comment: you just want to get the value of `cUID` ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)

Comment: This tool: http://smartbear.com/products/qa-tools/automated-testing-tools/ ?

Comment: @AaronDigulla yes, that's the tool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this page is opened in a browser, you can access the page's global script variables like this:

```
Sys.Browser().Page(url).contentDocument.Script.cUID
```